# How to create an atom template for python

Tags: python, atom-editor

I have the following class i am tired of writing it out every time. I need an atom template. For example if i were to type `luigt` and press enter the code would appear.

```
class TaskName(luigi.Task):
"""GENERAL TASK."""

def requires(self):
    """test."""
    return None

def run(self):
    """test."""
    pass

def output(self):
    """test."""
    return luigi.LocalTarget('default')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to the snippets [here](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/).

You can define code snippets in there and a shortcut. I think this is exactly what you are looking for.

**Extraction from the snippet page:**

There is a text file in your ~/.atom directory called snippets.cson that contains all your custom snippets that are loaded when you launch Atom. You can also easily open up that file by selecting the Edit > Snippets menu.

**Snippet Format**
So let's look at how to write a snippet. The basic snippet format looks like this:

```
'.source.js':
  'console.log':
    'prefix': 'log'
    'body': 'console.log(${1:"crash"});$2'
```

For more details, please have a look at the snippet page provided.